# Android - How to set familiy font "noto sans" in xml?

Tags: android, xml, fonts

I'm developing an android widget app targeting for above Lollipop (Android 5.0) users.

I have to use a font which is called "noto sans"(https://www.google.com/get/noto/#/) in my app for some reasons.

I heard it is contained in Lollipop, but i don't know how to use it in xml.

Anyone knows about it?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use custom fonts in layout file (XML). You have to use the custom fonts programmatically as shown below

```
String fontPath = "fonts/calibrib.ttf";

          // Loading Font Face
          Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), fontPath);

TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
txtView.setTypeface(tf);
```

Place your font inside assets folder. Here is for what above code is working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own TextView by overriding the TextView like this, you have to put the font in the assets folder:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setType(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setType(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setType(context);
    }

    private void setType(Context context){
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "foo.ttf"));

        this.setShadowLayer(1.5f, 5, 5, getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.black_shadow));
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<com.your.project.package.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/oppinfo_mtv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"  
        android:text="Player 1"
        />
```